# How to check when statistics was last executed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We've been having a number of issues with our indexes lately which our DBA team has attributed to statistics not having been run recently. This has made me wonder - how can I check if statistics have been recently updated via SQL Management Studio?

I apologize if this question isn't explaining this very well - I've only been introduced to statistics until now and prior to this would look to indexes whenever I've had performance related issues.

**Edit**:

I'm using the following but receiving a syntax error:

```
use *databasename*
exec sp_autostats *schema.tablename*
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**For your edit** - You need to enclose table name into single quotes:

```
EXEC sp_autostats 'tablename'
```

**and** for the original question

First - find the statistics you want to check:

[image: choose statistics]

Second - see its properties, and there you will see the last updated timestamp:

[image]

Or you may want to execute the following query:

```
SELECT t.name TableName, s.[name] StatName, STATS_DATE(t.object_id,s.[stats_id]) LastUpdated 
FROM sys.[stats] AS s
JOIN sys.[tables] AS t
    ON [s].[object_id] = [t].[object_id]
WHERE t.type = 'u'
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way to get information about statistics is through the command

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (<tablename>,<indexname>)
```

That will return information not just about when the stats where updated, but their size, density, how selective they are, and the histogram that shows the distribution of data. With all that, you can determine if those stats are up to date and effective.